# How should I display list of lists with parent and child combined

Tags: visualforce

I am having a data structure similar to this:

```
Class A 
{
    public String Name;
    public String status;
    public List<B>;
}
```

In the Visualforce page, I need to display both A and B's information in one table. Like below: 
[image]

Please note that A1 and B1 will be in the same line of the table.

I am not quite sure how should I achieve this in Visualforce by using apex:repeat. I am thinking of using another wrapper class to hold both A and B's information and if B is not the first child, the related A information can be blank. However, this still sounds a bit strange to me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a `List<Child__c>`. Within each row, you can then reference fields on `Parent__c` or `Child__c`.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!children}" var="child">
    <apex:column value="{!child.Parent__r.Name}" />
    <apex:column value="{!child.Name}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Make sure in your  query you `ORDER BY Parent__c`.

If you want to only display parent details for the first row in a grouping, you could use a wrapper like below:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Parent__c parent;
    public Child__c child;`
}
```

Then in your controller, you can do some algorithm along the following lines:

```
public List<Wrapper> wrappers { get; private set; }
public MyController()
{
    for (Parent__c parent : [/*query*/])
    {
        Boolean isFirstChild = true;
        for (Child__c child : parent.Children__r)
        {
            Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
            wrapper.child = child;
            if (isFirstChild)
            {
                wrapper.parent = parent;
                isFirstChild = false;
            }
            else
            {
                wrapper.parent = new Parent__c();
                // you need an empty record to avoid NullPointerException
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Adrian. However, if you look at the table, both B1, B2, B3 should have the parent A1. However, only the line with B1 should show related parent's information.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `List<Child__c>` and your list should be ordered by `parent__c`. In visualforce you can handle above thing as :

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Parent Name</th>
   <th>Child Name </th>
   <th>Child Description</th>
</tr>
<apex:varaible var="parentId" value="" />
<apex:repeat value="{!children}" var="child">
    <tr>
       <td>
           <apex:outputText value="{!IF(child.Parent__c != parentId , child.Parent__r.Name, ''}" />
       </td>
       <td>
          <apex:outputText value="{!child.Name}" />
       </td>
       <td>
          <apex:outputText value="{!child.Description__c}" />
          <apex:variable value="{!child.Parent__c}" var="parentId"/>
       </td>
    </tr> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I haven't fully understood this solution yet. But I am trying.

Comment: In VF, I have created a `variable` for parentId, by which we compare parents and set values based on the result.

Comment: This behavior is not really "supported", and also `children.Parent__c` should fail to compile.

Comment: There was a typo (`children` => `child`)

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think now this solution will work.

Comment: @LanceShi check the updated solution. If it works then it would be easy to implement.

Comment: @PragatiJain The reason I chose Adrian's solution is not your solution is not viable. With Apex:variable I do think this solution can be implemented - just a matter of details and how many tricks we can to play here. However, for me it is a bit harder to read and to implement. And I don't see the significant advantage of applying this. I do have learnt something from your approach though. Thank you for that.